# What's the difference between JBoss cluster and RHCS?

Tags: java, jboss, redhat

When deploying a Java EE application in a clustered way, this can be done using either JBoss cluster or Redhat cluster suite (RHCS).

What's the difference? When to use JBoss cluster and when to use RHCS?

Answer (score 1):

Two different use cases.

JBoss clustering is for application level clustering such as clustered single sign on, HA singleton beans, HTTP session replication, etc.

Red Hat cluster suite is for platform/OS level clustering such as fail over of critical services, IP load balancing, nodes fencing, etc.

They are mutually exclusive concepts. You do not need Red Hat Cluster Suite to do JBoss clustering. JBoss clustering is performed at the JBoss application server level which is tied to the underlying JDK. In fact you can run a cluster of JBoss nodes on a Windows server if you wish to do so.